# How to deploy GraphQL Apollo-Server on a local machine?

Tags: graphql

Follow the [official doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/) I have buit a simple graphql server, and use express to serve it locally (for development), I also build a web app which uses Apollo-Client to get the data from the server.

Now I want to deploy my Apollo-Server to another computer which is on the same LAN, you can consider it as the "PROD".

I saw on the official site it recommends using [Heroku](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/heroku/), but I don't need any cloud platforms. What are the steps to serve my Apollo-Serve on a local machine? (because it's internal use only, I also want to turn on the graphql playground)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. You have your GraphQL server running at `localhost:4000` (or any other port)
2. You have enabled the playground (it's enabled by default)
3. Your machine allows inbound network connections (at least from your LAN)

Then this is just a matter of figuring out what your machine's local network name or IP address is.

Let's say your local network name is `wtf.local` - then you should be able to connect to your server from another machine by going to the url `http://wtf.local:4000`

Or if you know your local IP, say `192.168.0.22`, then try `http://192.168.0.22:4000`